# How to check if the result string is equal to "TIN" and the result of code is "TIN NEBULA 1023-212"?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to check the string if a sentence has a word "TIN" but it says false when i try to use equal or '=='. Here is my code.

```
            if (!recognizer.isOperational()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
                SparseArray<TextBlock> items = recognizer.detect(frame);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                //get text from sb until there is no text
                for (int it = 0; it < items.size(); it++) {
                    TextBlock myItem = items.valueAt(it);
                    sb.append(myItem.getValue());
                    sb.append("\n");
                    if (myItem.getValue() == ("TIN")) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "VERIFIED ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "WRONG ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                //set text to edit text
                mResultEt.setText(sb.toString());
            }
```

Comment: Always use .equals() for String, never '=='

Comment: @mkemmerz for java, yes :)

Answer (score 2):

When writing `myItem.getValue()==("TIN")` you only check if the handles of the two objects are identical. To compare their contents, you must write `myItem.getValue().equals("TIN")`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to check if it contains the value "TIN" in string.
If you want to check value contain in a string then use below -

```
if (myItem.getValue().contains ("TIN")) {
    //... code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**if a sentence has a word "TIN"** means you want to check a particular word in a sentence.

So use, `myItem.getValue().toString().contains("TIN")`